# Laravel how to implement function to delete items from cart?

Tags: php, laravel, session, cart, shopping-cart

I have to delete item on shopping cart, and surprisingly after implementing the destroy function Laravel doesn't show any error (i'm very begginer on php & laravel). But the button delete doesn't do nothing. On click the url create a token like this:

`http://localhost:8000/cart?_token=9XiWI3YPPmkctOEPBsEoAyF4UeAkAG3hJLLXHTl9&_method=DELETE`

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <tr>
    <td><img src="{{ $product['item']['imagePath'] }}" class="img-cart"></td>
     <td><strong style="margin-top: 6px">{{ $product['item']['title'] }}</strong></td>
      <td>
       <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ $product['qty'] }}" style="margin-right: 20px" >
         
              <form method="POST" action="{{ route('cart.destroy', ['id' => $product['item']['id']]) }}" > 
              @csrf
              {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
              <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" class="btn btn-danger" />
                                        
              </form>
           </form>
         </td>
       <td>${{ $product['price'] }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/add-cart/{id}', [
          'uses' => 'ProductController@getAddToCart',
          'as' => 'addToCart'
      ]);
Route::get('/cart', [
          'uses' => 'ProductController@getCart',
          'as' => 'shoppingCart'
      ]);
Route::get('/del/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

ProductController:

```
/**
    *@return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('home', ['products'=> $products]);
    }

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id) 
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);
        
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    public function getCart()
    {
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return view('cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');

        $cart = new Cart($oldCart); 
        return view('cart', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->delete($product, $product->id);
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('cart');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route is a get rather than a delete. It should be:

```
Route::delete('/del/{id}', 'ProductController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```